# How can I slice a substring from a unicode string with Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, substring

I have a unicode string as a result : `u'splunk>\xae\uf001'`

How can I get the substring 'uf001'

as a simple string in python?

Comment: Do you mean you need the string - `'uf001` - or the actual character that it represents?

Comment: `s[-1]`....................

Comment: @AnandSKumar the actual string.

Answer (score 2):

The characters `uf001` are not actually present in the string, so you can't just slice them off. You can do

```
repr(s)[-6:-1]
```

or

```
'u' + hex(ord(s[-1]))[2:]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the actual string (as seen from comments) , just get the last character `[-1] index` , Example -

```
>>> a = u'splunk>\xae\uf001'
>>> print(a)
splunk>Â®ï€
>>> a[-1]
'\uf001'
>>> print(a[-1])
ï€
```

If you want the unicode representation (`\uf001`) , then take `repr(a[-1])` , Example -

```
>>> repr(a[-1])
"'\\uf001'"
```

`\uf001` is a single unicode character (not multiple strings) , so you can directly get that character as above.

You see `\uf001` because you are checking the results of `repr()` on the string, if you print it, or use it somewhere else (like for files, etc) it will be the correct `\uf001` character.

Comment: And if you want to have the characters `u'\uf001'` printed out, change that last one to `print(repr(a[-1]))`

Comment: According to comments, he wants the actual string it represents.

Comment: Yeah, it was hard to understand (since you asked him if he wanted the actual character or the string representation, and he replied 'the actual string' - which could mean either). Good answer either way.

Answer (score 1):

`u''` it is how a Unicode string is represented in Python source code. REPL uses this representation by default to display unicode objects:

```
>>> u'splunk>\xae\uf001'
u'splunk>\xae\uf001'
>>> print(u'splunk>\xae\uf001')
splunk>®
>>> print(u'splunk>\xae\uf001'[-1])

```

If your terminal is not configured to display Unicode or if you are on a narrow build (e.g., it is likely for Python 2 on Windows) then the result may be different.

Unicode string is an immutable sequence of Unicode codepoints in Python. `len(u'\uf001') == 1`: it does not contain `uf001` (5 characters) in it. You could write it as `u''` (it is necessary to declare the character encoding of your source file on Python 2 if you use non-ascii characters):

```
>>> u'\uf001' == u''
True
```

It is just a different way to represent exactly the same Unicode character (a single codepoint in this case).

Note: some user-perceived characters may span *several* Unicode codepoints e.g.:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'ё')
u'\u0435\u0308'
>>> print(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'ё'))
ё
```

Comment: In addition to your note, Python2 supports Astral characters in the same way JavaScript does: badly. `len(u'') == 2`.

Comment: @Amadan: only on a narrow Python build i.e., Windows. The same code would return 1 on Linux (wide build)

Comment: You are correct. OSX default is narrow as well, FWIW.